# Web service Automation through Karate Framework using Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I am facing the following issue:
I am writing web service automation testing using Intuit Karate framework through BDD Cucumber in Eclipse.
We are using "Scenario Outline" and passing value by "Examples" like this:
@parallel=false
@sanity
Feature: Data Integration
Background: 
  * url baseUrl 
  * configure ssl = true

```
        Scenario Outline: Generating csrf

        Given url securityChkUrl
        * print 'securityChkUrl in POST : ' , securityChkUrl
        And param type = 'json'
        And form field j_username = "<UserID>"
        And form field j_password = "<Password>"
        And header X-CSRF-TOKEN = csrf
        When method POST
        Then status 200
        And def csrfAfterLogin = responseHeaders['X-CSRF-TOKEN'][0]
        * print 'csrf token after successful login is : ' , csrfAfterLogin

Examples: 
|UserID|Password|
|Prosenjit123|Prosenjit@123456|
```

I want to pass a value as a variable instead of passing the value itself.

For example: instead of sending `Prosenjit123` and `Prosenjit@123456` as above, I would like to send `userName` and `PasswordForUserName` which will contain these values.
This doesnt seem to work, How could I do it?

Thanks
Prosenjit

Answer (score 0):

You can store the post response and CSRF token in the class/global variables(decide based on the language variable scope), then update your step to use the variable in the step def.